# Loud and high pitched mic audio during calls

Tags: audio, input, microphone, zoom

I use Ubuntu 20.04.1.

When I use apps like Zoom or Discord, my audio input is weird, where it gets distorted and becomes a very loud scary noise that keeps increasing to a higher pitch and volume (it's like the echo of white noise and high pitch).

The problem doesn't happen when I record myself speaking or if I use my mic in windows.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: use headphones .

Comment: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360046244692-Background-noise-suppression , https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115003279466-Enabling-option-to-preserve-original-sound : oh they forgot Linux Desktop support? So surprising... (not in prerequisites for not doing echo cancellation certainly means there is no echo cancellation at all). I guess these randomly found links (not tested) might be useful to get the functionality: https://github.com/lawl/NoiseTorch , https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/09/how-to-enable-echo-noise-cancellation.html